# "could not find function ggplot" - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to R but I have been using it for a few months.  Just now I started getting the error below - "could not find function ggplot" while running this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(sqldf)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
options(scipen =999) #disable scientific notation



#prepare data:

setwd("C:/Users/hayescod/Desktop/BuysToForecastTracking")
Buys_To_Forecast <- read.csv("BuysToForecastTrack.csv")

colnames(Buys_To_Forecast) <- c("Date", "BusinessSegment", "Material", "StockNumber", "POCreatedBy", "PlantCode", "StockCategory", "Description", "Excess", "QuantityBought", "WareHouseSalesOrders", "GrandTotal", "Comments" )
Buys_To_Forecast$PlantCode <-factor(Buys_To_Forecast$PlantCode) #update PlantCode to factor


#use SQL to filter and order the data set: 

btf <- sqldf("SELECT Date, 
                     SUM(QuantityBought) AS 'QuantityBought', 
                     Comments
              FROM   Buys_To_Forecast 
              GROUP BY Date, Comments
              ORDER BY Date")
#use ggplot:

ggplot(data=btf, aes(x=Date, y=QuantityBought)) + geom_point()
```

I have tried re-installing ggplot2, resetting my R session to no avail.  The full error is:

```
Error in ggplot(data = btf, aes(x = Date, y = QuantityBought)) : 
  could not find function "ggplot"
```

Any thoughts?

I will say I installed devtools right before this started happening so not sure if that played a role.

Thanks.

Comment: This might help https://community.rstudio.com/t/problems-with-loading-ggplot2/6250

Comment: hey - thank you very much - for a newcomer that is a bit of a weird message but I found the solution in that thread! Thanks a ton